# An error occurred while installing rugged

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, rubygems, gitlab, rugged

Following this tutorial [[link](http://blog.bobbyallen.me/2014/01/11/setup-your-own-private-github-server-using-gitlab-and-ubuntu-server-12-04-lts/)] to install gitlab on a dedicated server. I need to :

```
sudo -u git -H bundle install --deployment --without development test postgres aws
```

But an error occurred while installing rugged :

```
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /usr/local/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for cmake... no
ERROR: CMake is required to build Rugged.
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/usr/local/bin/ruby


    Gem files will remain installed in /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rugged-0.21.2 for inspection.
    Results logged to /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rugged-0.21.2/ext/rugged/gem_make.out
    An error occurred while installing rugged (0.21.2), and Bundler cannot continue.
    Make sure that `gem install rugged -v '0.21.2'` succeeds before bundling.
```

So I installed rugged -> I installed CMake & config-pkg :

```
/home/git/gitlab$ sudo gem install rugged
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed rugged-0.21.2
Parsing documentation for rugged-0.21.2
unable to convert "\xC0" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for lib/rugged/rugged.so, skipping
1 gem installed
```

But it doesnt change anything :

```
Errno::EACCES: Permission denied - /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rugged-0.21.2/LICENSE
An error occurred while installing rugged (0.21.2), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install rugged -v '0.21.2'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Any idea ?

Comment: Can the `git` user read `/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rugged-0.21.2/LICENSE` (he should)? Because you didd `sudo gem install rugged` so they might be owned by root.

Comment: You have a much more easy way to install GitLab in ubuntu, using the [gitlab omnibus package](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/blob/master/README.md)

Answer (score 106, accepted):

First, try installing cmake:

```
sudo apt-get install cmake
```

Then, repeat the command:

```
sudo -u git -H bundle install --deployment --without development test postgres aws
```

Comment: To me, running `sudo apt-get install cmake` was enough.

Comment: This has also fixed my issue `Make sure that `gem install rugged -v '0.25.0b2'` succeeds before bundling.` when trying to use `gem 'github-linguist'` in my `Gemfile` in rails. Cheers.

Comment: Why do so many Gem developers do this and leave install flows in terrible shape, leading to so many SO questions like this? Why don't Gem developers improve their instructions or error messages?

Answer (score 151):

For OSX if you're using homebrew:

```
brew install cmake 
bundle install
```

Comment: Still the case in 2022 :)

Comment: Still the case in 2023 :)

Comment: Still the case in 2023 november :)

Comment: Still the case in 2024

Answer (score 17):

For me, gem was complaining about pkg-config missing dependence, so I did:

```
sudo apt-get install pkg-config
```

and then

```
sudo gem install rugged -v '0.22.2'
```

after that, I revert to my older version of gitlab and re-run the script for the upgrade.

My older version of gitlab was 6.9.2 and the upgraded version 8.0.5

Answer (score 1):

Can fix this problem only that way:

download from https://cmake.org/download/. Extract the downloaded tar file and then:

```
cd $CMAKE_DOWNLOAD_PATH
./configure
make
make install
```

And after this steps I could successfully run:

```
gem install rugged -v '0.26.0'
```

Comment: works for Centos

Answer (score 1):

**Note: The above mentioned solutions did not work for me.**

---

Here is the error log I got

```
checking for gmake... no
checking for make... yes
Building Rugged using system libraries.
libgit2 version is not compatible, expected ~> 0.99.0
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.
```

It was mainly saying `libgit2 version is not compatible, expected ~> 0.99.0`

and I tried `gem install rugged -v '0.99.0'` and then `bundle install`.

then the problem is solved.

Comment: The above didn't work for you because you have a different error message than the question. The question refers to a `cmake` error.

Answer (score 1):

For me it was Openssl problem in a WSL ubuntu 20.04 env

Run
`apt install cmake libssl-dev`

might also help to run
`apt install ruby-dev pkg-config`

Answer (score 0):

Mac OSX 10.6 or later please refer to this url:

http://www.cmake.org/download/